# How to display dynamic list which is coming in JSON format from server?

Tags: android

I know something I have written wrong here, I am trying to display multiline items dynamically from JSON but getting following exception,

```
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.item.MultiLineItem.createView(MultiLineItem.java:44)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.view.ViewFactory.getView(ViewFactory.java:122)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.view.DocumentList.createView(DocumentList.java:52)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.view.ViewFactory.getContainer(ViewFactory.java:85)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.controller.Controller.createDocument(Controller.java:415)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.model.SublistChooser.checkNextListTemplate(SublistChooser.java:99)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.model.SublistChooser.checkNextListTemplate(SublistChooser.java:96)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.model.SublistChooser.start(SublistChooser.java:50)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.controller.Controller.startDocument(Controller.java:387)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.controller.Controller.startDocument(Controller.java:379)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.action.ActionExecutor.executeTaskAction(ActionExecutor.java:445)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.action.ActionExecutor.onAction(ActionExecutor.java:288)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.action.Action.execute(Action.java:133)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.nokia.view.PopupList$1.onClick(PopupList.java:72)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:920)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1037)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2449)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3073)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
01-22 11:18:27.814: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 11:18:27.973: D/dalvikvm(438): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 5% free 9758K/10247K, paused 9ms+27ms
01-22 11:18:34.123: I/Process(438): Sending signal. PID: 438 SIG: 9
```

This is the code I am getting `NullPointerException`, I don't know how to set view to List. `View` is returning `Null` but for normal `TextFields` its working file. Please post some helpful code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.nokia.view.BaseScreen;
import com.nokia.view.BaseView;

public class MultiLineItem extends Item implements BaseView{

    private HashMap items;
    private  ArrayList list;
    public MultiLineItem(BaseScreen pview){
        super(pview);
        list= new ArrayList();
        items = new HashMap();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public View getItem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view;
    }
    public void createView(JSONObject definition) {
        String header=definition.optString("header");
        items.put("header", header);
        String text = definition.optString("text");
        items.put("text", text);
        list.add(items);
        //((ListView)view).addFocusables(list, LIST);
    }

    public ArrayList getList(){
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Widget for that in `Android` you have to use `ListView` for that. In `ListView` set the `Adapter` and in Adapter you have to send all the data you get from `Json`. Here is the example for doing that [Android ListView Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/). This tutorial will give you idea how to use ListView in your Application.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I am doing this without using XML's, I am doing it in java code only ... just to achieve MultiLineItem...how i can do...    list.add(items); adding 1st header and returning null..its not adding 2nd header and list items ... anybody has any idea.....